# printing an Array in java with inputs from if-statement

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, printing

Please, I need help printing these arrays. In the method "IsPrime" it is testing if the inputs are prime and stores them in the array "prime[]" I set it to that big of an array because I can't possibly know the exact prime numbers the inputs will get and the same goes for the"palin"array. At the last for loop I am trying to print the results of the array of prime but the output I get are not the primes. I get "0000000000" thanks!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class p1c {  
    private static Scanner scan;
    public static void main(String[] args){
       scan = new Scanner(System.in);
       int z;
       for(z = 0; z<2; z++){
           System.out.println("\n Please enter the first integer number:" );
           int numx = scan.nextInt();
           System.out.println("Please enter the second integer number");
           int numy = scan.nextInt();
           if ( numx < numy){ 
               isPrime(numx,numy);
           }
           else{
               System.out.print("This is invalid, try again, x must be less than y");
               System.exit(0);
           }
      }
  }

  public static int reverse(int i){
      int reverse = 0;
      while (i!= 0){
          reverse = reverse * 10;
          reverse = reverse + i % 10;
          i = i/10;
      }
      return reverse;
  }

  public static void isPrime(int numx, int numy){
      int d = 0,c;
      int prime[] = new int[50];
      int palin[] = new int[50];
      for (int i=numx; i <= numy; i++ ){
          for (c=2; c<i; c++){
              int n = i%c;
              if (n==0){
                  break;
              }
          }
          if(i == c && i != 0 && c != 0){
              prime[i]=i;
          }
          if( reverse(i)== i){
              int palindrome = i;
              palin[palindrome]= palindrome;
          }
     }  
     for(int count = 0; count < prime.length;count ++){
          d++;
          System.out.print(prime[count]);
          if(d == 10){
              System.out.println();
              d=0;
          }
      }
   }                    
}
```

Comment: I suggest you fix your formatting using the formatter in your IDE, I also suggest you step through your code in your debugger to help debug your code. Note: Your program won't find that `10` is a palindrome even though `010` is a palindrome.

Comment: If you're using eclipse, try `ctrl+shift+f` to format your code (`alt+ctrl+l` for jetbrains I suppose). When you do that, think of the smallest piece of code that convies your problem and share that with us. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the help especially with the formatting tip.The issue about the palindrome is my fault, i forgot to mention that it is looking for a number that is prime and palindrome.

Comment: Where in your question do you mention anything about a palindrome?

Comment: Also give expected input and output.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue has to do with you choosing an array. So, when you go to print out the contents of your array it prints 50 elements - mostly 0 because that was what you initialized it to be.

Use a `List<Integer>` instead. Eg: 
`List <Integer> prime = new ArrayList<Integer> () ;`

Then in your if condition, when a prime is found, do `prime.add(i);`

When printing out contents of list, use `prime.size()` for upper bound of loop and `prime.get(count)` when printing out contents.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final working code if anyone wants or has ever has this crappy project!

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class p1c {

private static Scanner scan;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int z;
    for (z = 0; z < 2; z++) {

        System.out.println("\n Please enter the first integer number:");
        int numx = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter the second integer number");
        int numy = scan.nextInt();

        if (numx < numy) {
            isPrime(numx, numy);

        }

        else {
            System.out.print("This is invalid, try again, x must be less than y");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}

public static int reverse(int i) {

    int reverse = 0;
    while (i != 0) {
        reverse = reverse * 10;
        reverse = reverse + i % 10;
        i = i / 10;

    }
    return reverse;
}

public static void isPrime(int numx, int numy) {
    int d = 0, c;
    int x = 0;
    int prime[] = new int[1000000];
    int palin[] = new int[500000];

    for (int i = numx; i <= numy; i++) {

        for (c = 2; c < i; c++) {
            int n = i % c;
            if (n == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (i == c && i != 0 && c != 0) {

            prime[i] = i;

        }

        if (reverse(i) == i) {
            int palindrome = i;
            palin[palindrome] = palindrome;

        }
    }
    System.out.println("Prime:");
    for (int count = 0; count < prime.length; count++) {

        if (prime[count] != 0) {
            d++;
            System.out.print("\t" + prime[count]);

        }

        if (d == 10) {

            System.out.println();
            d = 0;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("\n palindromic Prime:");
    for (int counter = 0; counter < palin.length; counter++) {

        if (palin[counter] != 0) {
            x++;
            System.out.print("\t" + palin[counter]);
        }

        if (x == 10) {

            System.out.println();
            x = 0;
        }
    }
}
}
```